# Deploying Spring in WAS-ND

Tags: spring, deployment, websphere

I'm encountering this error whenever I deploy my .war file to WAS-ND.

```
Error Stack: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file <filename>

nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor 


Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
```

I did some research and found out that I needed the cglib and asm jars for this to work. Unfortunately, I already have them...

Jars:

```
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

I don't understand why it still won't work... Any help here? :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not talking about classnotfound exception. It simply states that a Class that "ClassVisitor" depends on is incompatible.  It could locate the class except that the version is different from what it expected it to be.

I would try this for a start. Look at this class and see the imports  used by this and see which Jars contain those classes and possibly one of them should hold the answers.

Btw what version of Spring are you using and have you ensured that all the dependent Jars are all compatible!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you are using applicationContext, Check whether its under source folder.

And also check jars under buildpath

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the org.springframework.asm jar. Apparently it's a bug that's known by IBM and a patch is to be released this October 29 for the fix. Hope this helps. :)

EDIT: Unfortunately, the patch didn't resolve the problem...